# how to replace part of a string with a const?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Thats my code:

```js
const searchTerm = `?term=${this.term}`;
const routeWithoutTerm = this.$route.fullPath.replace(searchTerm , '');
```

I want to remove `searchTerm` from `this.$route.fullPath` and save it in `routeWithoutTerm`, but this is obviously the wrong way. It just replaces nothing. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: Lets just say that at execution `this.term = 'help'` and `this.$route.fullPath = 'search/help?term=help'` and I want to remove `?term=help`

Comment: I think the issue is with `this.$route` or `this.term` - the js is ok. is it supposed to be `this.route` without the `$` perhaps?

Comment: can you provide context to what `this.term` and `this.$route.fullPath` values are at execution?

Comment: It's hard to help when the surrounding code and involved variables are not given. Can you provide these?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Nope. `this.$route` is how its supposed to be. It's vue code btw

Comment: @J.Pichardo I updated my post

Comment: then your js works - is there any errors in the console?

Comment: @J.Pichardo Nope...

Comment: Why not simply use `this.$route.path`? If you need to check the value of the option first, use `$route.query.term`. Your current solution is super brittle.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my problem.

I was having umlauts(ö, ä, ü) in my `searchTerm` so I had to use `encodeURI()` on my `searchTerm` first.

Answer (score 0):

try this to remove search param:

```js
const url = 'https://example.com/posts?page=5&sort=desc';

const urlObj = new URL(url);

urlObj.search = '';

const result = urlObj.toString();

console.log(result); // https://example.com/posts
```

[source](https://codingbeautydev.com/blog/javascript-remove-query-string-from-url/)

Answer (score -2):

Use substring() function to get the part you want and use replace() to replace it with whatever you want

```
const const1 = "adios";
const const2 = "muchasgracias";
var result = const2.replace(const2.substring(0,5), const1);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `var` is not `const`